# Show Last Modified Date in Wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, last-modified-date

I have some migrated Wiki pages from 2007 that are no longer showing their Last Modified Date in the footer. Is this not included Out of Box anymore? I can see the modified date in 'Page History' but not the Wiki page itself.

In the 2007 Page Layout there was this working tag:

```
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02"></span>
```

I also tried writing the following REST query but it returns the wrong user. It shows myself even though the ModifiedBy field is a different user.

```
/WIKI/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/WIKI/Wiki Pages/Home.aspx')?$select=TimeLastModified,ModifiedBy/Title,ModifiedBy/LoginName&$expand=ModifiedBy
```

Any suggestions on getting the Last Modified Date to display in Wiki Pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following example to get the Last Modified and Last Modified by Field for a page

```
// Get Item ID of the Page in the Document LIbrary
var sItemId = _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId;
if (sItemId != "" && sItemId != "0") 
{
    // Get GUID of the document library where the page is stored
    var spageListId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
    sPageListId = spageListId.replace("{", "'");
    sPageListId = spageListId.replace("}", "'");
    // Form the REST URL to get the Last Modified and Last Modified By Information
    var sRestApiRequestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid" + sPageListId + ")/items(" + sItemId + ")?$select=Modified,ID,Title,Editor/Id,Editor/Title,Editor/EMail,*&$expand=Editor";
}
```